Expression of relative root mean squared error (RRMSE)
I have been wondering for quite some time about the expression of the relative root mean squared error, RRMSE, as it is been considered in the literature. First of all, there seems to be no clear consensus on the expression itself, e.g., if you take a look at the expression of the error in [1], [2] and [3] you can see that they are all different expressions of a same named error.
The most common expression (as it seems to me) for this error follows
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
RRMSE(y,\hat{y}) = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n(y-\hat{y})^2}{\sum_{i=0}^ny^2}},
\end{equation}
for $y$ and $\hat{y}$ the measured and calculated data respectively. The issue in my opinion arises because of its sensitivity to the size of the data since $n$ runs wild in the previous expression. I understand it is intended to relativize the root mean squared error by means of the sample mean (or its root mean square), but in that case it should follow a reasoning similar to
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
RRMSE_{alt}(y,\hat{y}) = \frac{RMSE(y,\hat{y})}{RMS(y)} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n(y-\hat{y})^2}}{\sqrt{{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^ny^2}}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n(y-\hat{y})^2}{\sum_{i=0}^ny^2}}.
\end{equation}
To compare both expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$ I have considered a simple example with an objective and estimation functions evaluated over a range of $n$ values which will serve as the measured and calculated data respectively. The functions used are the following:
$$
f_{obj}(x) = x^2-3x+3.5, \quad f_{est}(x) = x^2-1.2x+2.5,
$$
and the values evaluated $\{-1, -1+\frac{3.5}{n}, -1+2 \cdot \frac{3.5}{n}, \cdots, 2.5 \}$.

The issue of the effect of the sample size in $(1)$ can be seen by simply varying $n$. I've coded in python a simple program to ilustrate this example:
import numpy as np

RRMSE_literature = lambda y,y_: np.sqrt((1/len(y))*np.sum((y-y_)**2)/np.sum(y**2))
RRMSE_alt = lambda y,y_: np.sqrt(np.sum((y-y_)**2)/np.sum(y**2))

literature_error_list = []
alternate_error_list = []

sample_sizes = [int(n) for n in np.linspace(20, 20000, 200)]
for n in sample_sizes:
    x = np.linspace(-1,2.5,n)
    y_m = x**2-3*x+3.5
    y_c = x**2-1.2*x+2.5
    literature_error_list.append(RRMSE_literature(y_m,y_c))
    alternate_error_list.append(RRMSE_alt(y_m,y_c))

When the obtained lists are displayed, it can be seen:

Which shows how while $(2)$ varies on a smaller scale and stabilizes quickly around a certain value ($\approx 0.55443$), $(1)$ continues to decrease in value as you increase $n$.
I have seen some posts discussing the expression of RRMSE:

Is there something like a Root Mean Square Relative Error (RMSRE)? Or: What is the name of this error?

What is the difference between RRMSE and RMSRE?

Can I say that the relative root mean squared error is the averaged percentage error?


But the expression considered there tends to be $(1)$ or a different one. Doesn't $(2)$ make more sense since it doesn't exhibit the sensitivity to $n$ that expression $(1)$ does?

In forecasting, the RRMSE is quite common, where it is defined as the RMSE of a "focal" forecasting method divided by the RMSE achieved by some benchmark method, like the historical mean. This makes a lot of sense, it's essentially the percentage reduction our focal method achieves over the benchmark. It's different from your equation (1), unless one uses the flat zero forecast as a benchmark.
